# Encode path to file on server and decode on client

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I have a path to file like `D:\\Folder1\\bin\\11m2011y\\sadfj34f3kl4fj34klfjkl34f.bin`
So, when i send in to JavaScript, i lose characters `:`, `\`, `.`

Is there way to encode this string on server side (.net) and then decode on client (javascript)?

Thx

**Answer**:

**.net**:System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode()

**javascript**:unescape()

Comment: why not put it in a hidden field?

Comment: What d u mean? I have string on server side and i send it to JavaScript. What hidden field?

Comment: Why not place the string in the `<input type="hidden">` field? and access that throught javascript...